# Teradata - Counting previous values

Tags: sql, count, sum, teradata

I am trying to sum previous values in a query as an intermediate step to accomplish another task. I want to sum previous values of 3,
for example

```
Type   value
A        3 
A        3
A        3
A        3
A        3
A        3
A        3
B        2.3
B        2.3 
B        3
B        2.3 
B        2.3 
B        3
B        2.3
```

and my ideal answers would be

```
Type   value   Previous 3's
A        3             0
A        3             1 
A        3             2
A        3             3
A        3             4
A        3             5
A        3             6
B        2.3           7
B        2.3           7
B        3             7
B        2.3           8
B        2.3           8
B        3             8
B        2.3           9
```

How would I achieve this in Teradata or SQL?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column specifying the ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  To count previous values, you need a column that specifies the ordering, and you don't have one in your question.

You can use a cumulative count or sum:

```
select t.*,
       count(case when value = 3 then 1) over
           (order by ? rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
from t;
```

The `?` is for the column specifying the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this at least in MYSQL:

```
create table teadata(Type varchar(1), value number);
insert into teadata(Type, value) values('A', 3);
insert into teadata(Type, value) values('A', 3);
insert into teadata(Type, value) values('A', 3);
insert into teadata(Type, value) values('B', 3);
insert into teadata(Type, value) values('B', 2.3);

select type, value, (@sum := @sum + (case when value = 3 then 1 else 0 end)) as cumesum 
    from teadata t cross join (select @sum := 0) params;
```

This will print:

```
+------+-------+---------+
| type | value | cumesum |
+------+-------+---------+
| A    |     3 |       1 |
| A    |     3 |       2 |
| A    |     3 |       3 |
| B    |     3 |       4 |
| B    |   2.3 |       4 |
+------+-------+---------+
```

The trick in this case is to use a variable @sum together with a case statement. This works on MySQL. Not sure about Teradata.